# Point on a line closest to the origin, general formula using linear algebra only

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, projection

Given a line $\ell$ in $\mathbb R^2$ containing points $p, q$, find point $r$ on $\ell$ closest to the origin, using linear algebra only (no calculus).

My answer is below, but I seem to have made a mistake.  Can you help me find my mistake?

**Answer:** The point $r$ is given by the formula
$$t = \frac{||q||^2}{||q - p||^2} \\
r = tp +(1-t)q
$$
*Notation:* We use $x$ to indicate both the point $x$ and a vector from the origin to the point, and don't always distinguish the two.

**Proof:** A line is an affine combination of its points, so that the points on the line are precisely $tp + (1-t)q$ for $t \in \mathbb R$.  The closest point on line is the unique point on the line whose dot product with a vector parallel to the line is zero.  The vector $q - p$ is parallel to the line. So we need to find a $t$ such that $[tp +(1-t)q] \cdot [q-p] = 0$:

$$[tp +(1-t)q] \cdot [q-p] = 0 \\
2t(p\cdot q) -t||p||^2 - t||q||^2 + ||q||^2 = 0\\
t(||p||^2 + ||q||^2 - 2p \cdot q) = ||q||^2 \\
t = \frac {||q||^2}{||q-p||^2} \\
$$

**Problem Example:** Let $p=(1,3,3)$ and $q = (0,2,1)$.  Then $t= \frac {||q||^2}{||q-p||^2} = \frac{5}{4}$ and $r = tp + (1-t)q = \frac 5 4 (1,3,3) - \frac {1}4 (0,2,1) = (\frac 5 4, \frac {13}4, \frac {14}{4})$.  However, this does not seem to be the answer calculus gives, so I must be making a mistake.

Comment: your exploration give me the chance to review this calcs: +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the use of pseudo inverse:

Your line is $\ell(t)=(p-q)t+q$ and you are seeking $t_0$ such that
$$(p-q)t_0+q\approx\vec0,$$
so $(p-q)^{\top}(p-q)t_0+(p-q)^{\top}q\approx0$.

Hence
$$t_0=\dfrac{(q-p)\bullet q}{\|p-q\|^2}.$$

**Addendum**

*Let's straighten a bit your idea:*

\begin{eqnarray*}
[tp+(1-t)q]\cdot[q-p]&=&tp\cdot[q-p]+(1-t)q\cdot[q-p]\\
&=&tp\cdot q-tp\cdot p+(1-t)q\cdot q-(1-t)q\cdot p\\
&=&tp\cdot q-t||p||^2+(1-t)||q||^2-p\cdot q+tp\cdot q\\
&=&2tp\cdot q-t||p||^2+||q||^2-t||q||^2-p\cdot q\\
&=&-t(||q||^2-2p\cdot q+||p||^2)+||q||^2-p\cdot q\\
&=&-t||p-q||^2+||q||^2-p\cdot q\\
&=& .\ .\ . 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks.  Which line in my "proof" is wrong? I'm unable to find the error.

Comment: you should be able to find by contrasting, your first steps above versus version here. . .  I am almost convinced myself that you will see the $-p\cdot q$ missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for $t$ is incorrect.Write the position vector as $\mathbf {r=q}+t(\mathbf{p-q})$ The equation $\mathbf{r \bullet (p-q)}=0$ gives$$t=\frac{\mathbf{-q\bullet(p-q)}}{\mathbf{(p-q) \bullet (p-q)}}$$

Comment: . n i c e . . . the very soul of pseudo inverse